# How do I give PyCharm access to my /private/etc/hosts file?

Tags: macos, file, hosts

How do I give PyCharm access to this file?

Comment: You don't.  There is no scenario where editing /etc/hosts with PyCharm is a good idea.

Comment: @MarcWilson While I would just use `vi` or `nano` to edit `/etc/hosts` I see no reason why others shouldn't use an IDE for this :-)

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123599/how-to-edit-the-etc-hosts-file?rq=1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212389/keyboard-maestro-how-to-write-to-etc-hosts-file?rq=1 and similar questions.